# Textures messed up after exporting!

Tags: texturing, export

Whenever I try to export this model as any format(.blend, .3ds, .fbx) and try to open it on any other program other than blender, the textures get messed up but when i open it in Blender, the textures are normal.

[image]

but when i try to use it in Unity3D for example:

[image]

that zombie appears XD.

also if I export it as .fbx and use it in Unity3D, the same thing happens!

Then I used that .fbx file to open it in VS2012 and I got this:

[image]

What are we doing wrong?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Are all your textures UV-mapped in Blender? Other formats might not support the different texture mapping methods that Blender supports.